# Shared pointer in rust arrays

Tags: arrays, rust, smart-pointers

I have two arrays:

```
struct Data {
    all_objects: Vec<Rc<dyn Drawable>>;
    selected_objects: Vec<Rc<dyn Drawable>>;
}
```

`selected_objects` is guarenteed to be a subset of `all_objects`. I want to be able to somehow be able to add or remove *mutable* references to selected objects.

I can add the objects easily enough to `selected_objects`:

```
Rc::get_mut(selected_object).unwrap().select(true);
self.selected_objects.push(selected_object.clone());
```

However, if I later try:

```
for obj in self.selected_objects.iter_mut() {
    Rc::get_mut(obj).unwrap().select(false);
}
```

This gives a runtime error, which matches the documentation for `get_mut`: "Returns None otherwise, because it is not safe to mutate a shared value."

However, I really want to be able to access and call arbitrary methods on both arrays, so I can efficiently perform operations on the selection, while also being able to still perform operations for all objects.

It seems `Rc` does not support this, it seems `RefMut` is missing a `Clone()` that alows me to put it into multiple arrays, plus not actually supporting `dyn` types. `Box` is also missing a `Clone()`. So my question is, how do you store writable pointers in multiple arrays? Is there another type of smart pointer for this purpose? Do I need to nest them? Is there some other data structure more suitable? Is there a way to give up the writable reference?

Comment: `elected_objects is guarenteed to be a subset of all_objects` - so it's a [`slice`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.slice.html)?

Comment: I don't think, they are not guaranteed to be continuous or evenly spaced. It's just an arbitrary subset

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why can't I store a value and a reference to that value in the same struct?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32300132/why-cant-i-store-a-value-and-a-reference-to-that-value-in-the-same-struct)

Answer (score 1):

Ok, it took me a bit of trial and error, but I have a ugly solution:

```
struct Data {
    all_objects: Vec<Rc<RefCell<dyn Drawable>>>;
    selected_objects: Vec<Rc<RefCell<dyn Drawable>>>;
}
```

The `Rc` allows you to store multiple references to an object. `RefCell` makes these references mutable. Now the only thing I have to do is call `.borrow()` every time I use a object.

While this seems to work and be reasonably versitle, I'm still open for cleaner solutions.